# how to pass object data from one controller to another controller in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Actually I am trying to fill a form in angularjs and its data is recieved in one of the controller...i need to pass the same data to another controller which is needed to be shown on the another web page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should  make use of angular service to do the same.

Create a service, that will hold model variables.

```
angular.service("dataService", function() {
    this.value1 = "";  
});
```

Then you can reference that service in your controllers,

```
angular.controller("myCntrl1", function($scope, dataService) {
    $scope.value1 = dataService.value1;
});


angular.controller("myCntrl2", function($scope, dataService) {
    $scope.value1 = dataService.value1;
});
```